# Save as using Ionic for mobile - How to show a save dialog in Android?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

How can I export a json as a file using Ionic running as apk in Android?

There are many things that I can do when using browser on PC, but when using Android I can't download.

I used a "a link" and ngx-filesaver, both don't show a save dialog.

How to show a save dialog in Android?

This is my template html:

```html
<ion-button class="child" color="medium" (click)="saveFile()">Export</ion-button>

<ion-button class="child" color="medium" (click)="onSave()">Save</ion-button>
```

ts:

```js
  import { FileSaverService } from 'ngx-filesaver';
  ...
  constructor(private fileSaverService: FileSaverService) { }

  saveFile(): void {
    const dlink: HTMLAnchorElement = document.createElement('a');
    dlink.download = 'file.txt';
    const content: string = 'content';
    dlink.href = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-16,' + content;
    dlink.click();
  }
  onSave(){
    this.fileSaverService.saveText('content', 'fileName.txt');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't do 'Save As' on mobile, but you can create file on public folder to allow user to get it.
Try with [cordova file plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file)

Read [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files) to see in which folders you can save files

Comment: unfortunately this plugin seems only to write files inside private directory owned by application.

Comment: You have to use the `externalRootDirectory` flag